# ArgumentError: Unknown key: origin using geokit-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geokit

I have a rails 4 app where I am trying to find all applications within N number of miles. Based on geokit-rails documention [HERE](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails#how-to-find-all-stores-within-10-miles-of-a-given-address) I should be able to do:

```
SapApplication.find(:all, :origin=>'100 Spear st, San Francisco, CA', :within=>10)
```

When I try and execute the command above in the console I get the error:

```
ArgumentError: Unknown key: origin
```

The SapApplication model has `acts_as_mappable` and attributes for lat/lng.

Just as an aside `SapApplication.by_distance(:origin => [37.792,-122.393])` does work, so I at least know geokit is installed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have [some new scopes](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails#new-scopes-to-use) so you could do:

```
SapApplication.within 10, origin: '100 Spear st, San Francisco, CA'
```

Comment: Thanks! The first suggestion using a where clause does not work. I get the error `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column sap_applications.origin does not exist`, but the 2nd suggestion just using .within does work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer so it could help others.